# Why does setting the "disabled" property to false also remove the "disabled" attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I have a button which is initially disabled:

```
<button disabled="disabled">Lorem ipsum</button>
```

For this button, `button.getAttribute('disabled')` returns `"disabled"`. However, when I enable this button with JavaScript:

```
button.disabled = false;
```

then `button.getAttribute('disabled')` starts returning `null`.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Rhj3c/1/

Why is that? Shouldn't `.getAttribute()` return the value from the original HTML source code? How do I then determine if the button was disabled in the original HTML source code?

Comment: It removes the attribute because the button can no longer have a disabled attribute when it's not disabled. Some properties *do* change the attributes if it's needed.

Answer (score 5):

> Shouldn't `.getAttribute()` return the value from the original HTML source code?

No, as per [the specification](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes) (emphasis mine):

> If a reflecting IDL attribute is a `boolean` attribute, then on getting the IDL attribute must return true if the content attribute is set, and false if it is absent. On setting, **the content attribute must be removed if the IDL attribute is set to false**, and must be set to the empty string if the IDL attribute is set to true. (This corresponds to the rules for [boolean content attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute).)

> How do I then determine if the button was disabled in the original HTML source code?

Check it before it changes. If the problem really is limited to “the original HTML source code” and not “what the element started out as” (for example, if it was created in JavaScript), that could be just a:

```
var originallyDisabled = Array.prototype.slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[disabled]')
);
⋮
if (originallyDisabled.indexOf(button) !== -1) {
    …
}
```

Comment: If it's disabled via javascript, you can check if it was already disabled or not, by checking the source code (**not** using Firebug/other dev tools while turns up when you press F12, instead by using Ctrl+U, the actual page received from the server).

Comment: @xFortyFourx: They're talking about a runtime check in the code.

Comment: @cookiemonster ah ok, thank you. I didn't see OP asking that.

Comment: That's just stupid. Why can't it be like with `<input value="…">` where setting the property doesn't affect the attribute, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/bKGLk/? If there's really no way to retrieve the original disabled-state from the HTML source code (with standard API), than that's really stupid.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: What's even more fun is that for a `button` element, changing the `.value` property *does* update the `"value"` attribute, unlike the `input` element. http://jsfiddle.net/Rhj3c/5/

Comment: @cookiemonster That's just… sad. :p

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I don’t know why it’s specified that way, but it is: “The value content attribute gives the default value of the input element. When the value content attribute is added, set, or removed, if the control's dirty value flag is false, the user agent must set the value of the element to the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or the empty string otherwise, and then run the current value sanitization algorithm, if one is defined.” It seems silly. I’d guess it had something to do with CSS, but `[disabled]` doesn’t reflect the JavaScript property/attribute there, either

Comment: @minitech Well, anyway, I've asked on W3C's mailing list: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2014May/0001.html

Answer (score 1):

The disabled attribute is a `Boolean` attribute and when present, it specifies that the  element should be disabled if not present then it's enabled and it could be used as:

```
<!-- Disabled -->
<button disabled>Lorem ipsum</button>
```

It could be used as a `property` ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rhj3c/4/)):

```
var button = document.querySelector('button');
console.log(button.disabled); // true if present, false if not

// Or this
console.log(button.hasAttribute('disabled')); // true if present false if not
```

Update ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/bKGLk/2/)):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.value = 'Dynamic value';
console.log(input.getAttribute('value')); // "Initial value" attribute is in source
console.log(input.value); // "Dynamic value" property is in ram, rendered on the screen
```

Using `input.value` you set property in `ram` not in `source`, you need to use `setAttribute` to change the`source`, is that you asked for ?

Comment: My point is that setting the property should not affect the attribute. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/bKGLk/

Comment: No, I don't want to change the source. I want to **retrieve** the value from the source. It works for the `value` attribute, but not for the `disabled` attribute.